# JavaFX: Add a lot of Nodes to a FlowPane in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a FlowPane where a lot of elements are added (~1000), each one of these elements contains an ImageView and some other elements and is loaded from an fxml file. With this many entries, it takes a long time until the nodes are rendered, and then they are displayed all at once.

Because of that, I would like to add the nodes one by one, using a thread. I tried the following:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Object v : collection.getObjects()) {
            addEntry(v);
            flowPane.requestLayout();
        }

    }
});
```

What addEntry() does is basically just loading the Node from the fxml and adding it to the flowPane.

With this code, the flowPane is rendered immediately, but the nodes still appear all at once.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your runlater is doing everything at once.  It's like one call to update the gui with all the nodes.  It needs to be called repeatedly in a loop.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FlowPaneTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
        flow.getChildren().add(new Text("Starting "));
        Task task = new Task() {
            @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {
                //for (Object v : collection.getObjects()){
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {//use your loop instead
                    Platform.runLater(()->{
                        flow.getChildren().add(new Text("adding node "));
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        Scene scene = new Scene(flow, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();
    }
}
```